# AND operation in WHERE clause if IF condition satisfy

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Suppose I have a variable `@hasAge` which can have value either `1` or `0`.

I want to write a SELECT query with where clause in which I want to check certain condition if `@var` is 1 otherwise I don't want to check that condition.
Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM My_Table mt
WHERE mt.name = 'abcd'
AND
IF(@hasAge)
mt.age > 10
```

So I want to compare my.age > 10 only if `@hasAge` is `1`

I dont want to have 2 different select statement like this:

```
if(@hasAge)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM My_Table mt
    WHERE mt.name = 'abcd'
    AND
    mt.age > 10
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM My_Table mt
    WHERE mt.name = 'abcd'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
WHERE mt.name = 'abcd'
AND (@hasAge = 0 OR mt.age > 10)
```

It means that if `@hasAge = 0` then the part after the OR is irrelevant, and if `@hasAge <> 0` then the part after the OR is applied.